# Inner div of scrollable horizontal container to have the width of the elements inside it

Tags: html, css

Sorry if I couldn't be clear in the title, but checking out the following jsFiddle will clear out what I want to do:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29tub5xs/)

I have a horizontally scrollable container that contains a div, and in that div i have several inline-block container. I want the inner container's border to span the whole width of the scrollable area. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
    <div>item 4</div>
    <div>item 5</div>
    <div>item 6</div>
    <div>item 7</div>
    <div>item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.innerContainer {
  border-top: solid 1px red;
}

.innerContainer div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just move `overflow-x: auto;`

from `.container`

to `.innerContainer`

or

use `width:max-content` in `.innerContainer`

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.innerContainer {
  border-top: solid 1px red;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.innerContainer div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<h3>
I want the red border to expand all the width of the scrollable container.
</h3>
<div class="container">
  <div class="innerContainer">
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
    <div>item 4</div>
    <div>item 5</div>
    <div>item 6</div>
    <div>item 7</div>
    <div>item 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I want the scrollbar to be on the outer container

Comment: use `width: max-content;`  in `.innerContainer`

Answer (score 0):

```
.innerContainer {
  width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: Generally, an explanation with code is appreciated. Otherwise, your answer may be deleted.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27273970).